# Create an array with multiple functions in it

Tags: node.js, promise.all

How can I create an array like this:

```
[foo(1,3), foo(5,7)]
```

with `Array.map` to put in to a `Promise.all` function in node.js?

Example:

```
const foo = [1,2,3]

function increment(n) {
  console.log(n + 1)
}

Promise.all(
  foo.map(n  => {
    return increment(n)
  })
)
```

Expected output:

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: You need to return `n + 1` from `increment`. You don't need to use promises / Promise.all as nothing asynchronous is happening here. If this is just an example, then `increment` should return a promise that resolves to your counter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is just missing the `async` keyword at the increment function and a return statement.

Adding `async` will return a promise and your foo.map will return an array of promises.

For example:

```
const foo = [1,2,3]

async function increment(n) {
  return n + 1;
}

const arrayOfPromises = foo.map(n  => {
    return increment(n);
})

console.log("arrayOfPromises", arrayOfPromises)

Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Output:

```
arrayOfPromises [ Promise { 2 }, Promise { 3 }, Promise { 4 } ]

[ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store functions in an array with arguments, you could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
function foo(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const arr = [foo.bind(null, 1, 2), foo.bind(null, 4, 2)]

const result = arr.map(f => f());
// result should be [3, 6]
```

Demonstration with REPL:

```
> function foo(a, b) { return a+b; }
undefined
> foo(1, 2)
3
> const arr = [foo.bind(null, 1, 2), foo.bind(null, 4, 2)]
undefined
> arr
[ [Function: bound foo], [Function: bound foo] ]
> arr.map(f => f());
[ 3, 6 ]
```